# jQuery - How to write text values to a hidden field for later use?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the latest and greatest jQuery.

I have a form with three text fields and three hidden fields. When you type in a text field, the value will be passed into the respective hidden field, which will later be accessed by other means.

```
FirstName value should be passed to FirstNameTemp
LastName value should be passed to LastNameTemp
Pseudonym value should be passed to PseudonymTemp
```

The following code is not working for me, though I swear it was working yesterday.  I am using FireFox and Firebug. I can watch the value of FirstNameTemp change, which seems to work fine in the code, but nothing else works property.

Is there anything wrong with this? Am I missing something obvious?

```
<input type='hidden' value="" id="FirstNameTemp">
<input type='hidden' value="" id="LastNameTemp">
<input type='hidden' value="" id="PseudonymTemp">

<input type='text' value="" class="Search" id="FirstName"><br>
<input type='text' value="" class="Search" id="LastName"><br>
<input type='text' value="" class="Search" id="Pseudonym"><br>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".Search").keyup(function() {
    var FirstName = $("#FirstName").val();
    var LastName = $("#LastName").val();
    var Pseudonym = $("#Pseudonym").val();
    // COPY ENTITIES TO TEMP ENTITIES
    $("#FirstNameTemp").val(FirstName);
    $("#LastNameTemp").val(LastName);
    $("#PseudonymTemp").val(Pseudonym);
});

});
```

EDIT

I opened and closed my browser and rebooted my machine. Nothing worked. So, I downloaded Firefox and FireBug and reinstalled. It worked just fine.

Thanks to all of you for the help and good ideas. You guys ROCK!!!

Comment: Works fine for me - http://jsfiddle.net/urZUT/1/ Made the hidden fields text boxes so you can see the value change.

Comment: According to your question, the hidden input with id "FirstNameTemp" changes but the rest do not - is this correct?

Comment: You are missing something because it works for me! Are you developing in something like ASP? Are your `id`s asctually coming through as `FirstName` exactly?

Comment: Works fine for me too (although the capitalized class name gives me the heebie-jeebies :)

Comment: Although, I saw some weird behavior on firebug, sometimes the value is set in the DOM (according to firebug/a get access to the value), but the HTML value in the HTML displayed in firebug does not refresh.

Comment: This looks fine to me too. Note that you don't have to use a hidden field if you don't want to. If you're keeping it all client-side (ie. you're not POSTing this data somewhere expecting those hidden fields), you can use jQuery to attach data to any DOM element. Here's a jsFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/dHMfp/1

Comment: @Py, it seems that it's working only intermittently. After the keyup, you can properly alert the value of the FirstNameTemp field, but it doesn't show up in the hidden field. Weird.

Comment: Do you need it on keyup? How about onblur so it only updates when the user moves away from the textbox, should be better for performance too?

Comment: What if they don't move away from the textbox?

Comment: That's why I asked if he needed it on keyup first ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do it like this:

```
$(".Search").keyup(function() {

    $('#'+this.id+'Temp').val($(this).val());

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/each/mtFt6/

Comment: Why not write it like that? Because I get paid for coding by the character. Your code would make a dent in my paycheck. A loop would KILL my paycheck.

Comment: @Evik +1 your comment as I *assume* you are kidding (however I have heard of people getting paid by the line arrrrrgghgghg)

Comment: Yes, I am kidding. Your efficient code is difficult to read for me though. I usually write inefficiently until I really understand what I am trying to do. And efficient code can be hard to diagnose. Rest assured, I'll be using your sample though.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".Search").keyup(function() {
       var targetId = "#" + $(this).attr("id") + "Temp";
       $(targetId).val($(this).val());
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample of efficient coding. The other guy's sample seems just a little bit better, so I am implementing that.  Thanks!!!